# What does attribute "as" do in "param" element?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've faced with the next code in `xls` transformation:

```
<xsl:param name="e" as="element()"/>
```

I'm struggling, what does `as="element()"` mean here? I've checked several resources:

- [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_param.asp)
- [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/Element/param)

But there is nothing about `as` attribute for `param` element. Do anybody know the meaning and purpose of the attribute?

Comment: Go to the source: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#parameter-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best documentation source is [w3](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#parameters). From documentation:

```
<!-- Category: declaration -->
<xsl:param
  name = eqname
  select? = expression
  as? = sequence-type
  required? = boolean
  tunnel? = boolean
  static? = boolean >
  <!-- Content: sequence-constructor -->
</xsl:param>
```

> The xsl:param element has an optional as attribute, which specifies the required type of the parameter. The value of the as attribute is a SequenceType. If the as attribute is omitted, then the required type is item()*.

You can read more about "as" attribute in [that section](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#parameter-type).

Thanks, [michael.hor257k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3016153/michael-hor257k).